# How to filter an 2D array to get single items?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an 2D array created with:

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arr[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = {
          value: 0,
        };
      }
    };
arr[4][3].value = 2;
arr[3][4].value = 2;
arr[2][5].value = 2;
```

How can I extract objects containing `.value == 2`? When I use filtering:

```
let filteredServices = arr.filter((sth) => sth.some((subElement) => subElement.value == 2));
console.log(filteredServices);
```

Output are 3 rows, where there is a `value == 2`, each row contains 10 items:

```
0: Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
1: Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
2: Array(10) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

Is there a way to get single array item without using this again?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j].value == 2) {
          //add item to the result
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `arr.flat().filter(({ value }) => value === 2)`

Comment: It worked perfect. Thank you!